# Primitive element theorem without building field extensions

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, galois-theory, fields, constructive-mathematics

Is there are nice way to prove the primitive element theorem without using field extensions?

The primitive element theorem says that if $x$ and $y$ are algebraic over $F$ and $y$ is separable over $F$, then there exists a $z \in F(x,y)$ such that $F(x,y) = F(z)$.  In the case where $F$ is infinite, $z$ can be expressed in the form $x + {\lambda}y$ with $\lambda \in F$.  In fact, almost any $\lambda$ will do.  There are only a finite number of exceptions.  These exceptions are $\frac{\alpha_i - x}{y - \beta_j}$ where $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_j$ range over the (other) roots of the minimal polynomials of $x$ and $y$ respectively.

But in order to talk about $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_j$ we need to build a field extension where the minimal polynomials of $x$ and $y$ split.  This is the step I'm hoping to avoid.

Perhaps we can build a polynomial in $F[x]$ whose roots are $\frac{\alpha_{i_1} - \alpha_{i_2}}{\beta_{j_1} - \beta_{j_2}}$ and simply avoid picking $\lambda$s which are roots of this polynomial, and then use whatever properties this polynomials has to prove that this works.

Or maybe there is another completely different way of proving the primitive element theorem while avoiding building field extensions.

I found [a nice proof](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/separable2.pdf) that $x$ is separable over $F$ if and only if every $y \in F(x)$ is separable over $F$ that avoids building field extensions.  It uses derivations instead.  Now I'm hoping to do the same with the primitive element theorem.

Edit: I'll try to give some motivation. Adding roots of polynomials to fields in constructive mathematics is more difficult than in classical mathematics (because irreducibility is undecidable). It only works for countable fields, and then you have no guarantee that the original field will be a decidable subset of the new field. Yes, it can be done, but it seems like a pain. There is another way too using double negation translations, but it also seems like a pain. Instead I'd rather avoid the whole issue of *building* splitting fields, if I can, and it seems tantalizingly close to possible.  After all, the only reason splitting fields are used here is to build a finite set of elements *in the base field* to avoid.

Comment: You can build this polynomial using resultants, but I'm not sure no splitting field is used during the proof...

Comment: Resultants are so much more confusing and computationally intensive than any sort of proof using splitting fields.

Comment: @Russell: I think that the proof of the primitive element theorem in Zariski and Samuel's "Commutative Algebra" (Page 84 in my 1965 edition) gives the kind of construction you are looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I have a proof which meets your conditions. I relied on [this write up](http://www.math.washington.edu/~greenber/PrimElem.pdf) of the standard proof as a reference.

**Lemma 1:** Let $K/F$ be an extension of fields, and let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be polynomials in $F[x]$. Let $d_F(x)$ be the GCD of $f$ and $g$ in $F[x]$ and let $d_K(x)$ be the GCD of $f$ and $g$ in $K[x]$. Then $d_F(x)$ and $d_K(x)$ coincide up to a scalar factor.

**Proof:** Since $d_F(x)|f(x)$ and $d_F(x)|g(x)$ in $K[x]$, we have $d_F(x)|d_K(x)$. Now, there are polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ in $F[x]$ such that $f(x) p(x) + g(x) q(x) = d_F(x)$. So $d_K(x) | d_F(X)$. Since $d_F(x)$ and $d_K(x)$ divide each other, they only differ by a scalar factor.

**Lemma 2:** Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be polynomials with $g(0) \neq 0$. Then, for all but finitely many $t$, the polynomials $f(tx)$ and $g(x)$ have no common factor.

**Proof:** Let $f(x) = f_m x^m + \cdots + f_1 x + f_0$ and $g(x) = g_n x^n + \cdots + g_1 x + g_0$. If $f(tx)$ and $g(x)$ HAVE a nontrivial common factor, then there are polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)$, of degrees $\leq n-1$ and $\leq m-1$, such that 
$$f(tx) p(x)=g(tx) q(x).$$ 
This is $m+n$ linear equations on the $m+n$ coefficients of $p$ and $q$. 
Writing this out in coefficients, the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
f_m t^m & \cdots & f_1 t & f_0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & f_m t^m & \cdots & f_1 t & f_0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\ddots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & f_m t^m & \cdots & f_1 t & f_0 \\
g_n & \cdots & g_1 & g_0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & g_n & \cdots & g_1 & g_0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\ddots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & g_n & \cdots & g_1 & g_0
\end{pmatrix}$$
has nontrivial kernel. The determinant of this matrix is a polynomial in $t$, with leading term $(f_m)^n (g_0)^n t^{mn} + \cdots$. (Recall that $g_0 \neq 0$.) So, for all but finitely many $t$, this matrix has nonzero determinant and $f(tx)$ and $g(x)$ are relatively prime. QED.

Now, we prove the primitive element theorem (for infinite fields). Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$, in $K$, be algebraic and separable over $F$, with minimal polynomials $f$ and $g$. We will show that, for all but finitely many $t$ in $F$, we have $F(\alpha - t \beta) = F(\alpha, \beta)$.

Let $f(x) = (x -\alpha) f'(x -\alpha)$ and $g(x) = (x - \beta) g'(x - \beta)$. Since $\beta$ is separable, we know that $g'(0) \neq 0$. Note that $f'$ and $g'$ have coefficients in $K$. By Lemma 2, for all but infinitely many $t$ in $F$, the polynomials $f'(ty)$ and $g'(y)$ have no common factor. Choose a $t$ for which no common factor exists. Set $F' = F(\alpha - t \beta)$; our goal is to show that $F'=F(\alpha, \beta)$.

Set $h_t(x) = f(tx + \alpha-t \beta)$. Note that $h_t(x)$ has coefficients in $F'$. We consider the GCD of $h_t(x)$ and $g(x)$.

Working in $K$, we can write $h_t(x) =  t (x - \beta) f'(t (x- \beta))$ and $g(x) = (x-\beta) g'(x-\beta)$. By the choice of $t$, the polynomials $f'(t (x- \beta))$ and $g'(x-\beta)$ have no common factor, so the GCD of $h_t(x)$ and $g(x)$, in the ring $K[x]$, is $x-\beta$.

By Lemma 1, this shows that $x - \beta$ is in the ring $F'[x]$. In particular, $\beta$ is in $F'$. Clearly, $\alpha$ is then also in $F'$, as $\alpha= (\alpha - t \beta) + t \beta$. We have never written down an element of any field larger than $K$. QED.

Comment: That said, let me reiterate my objection to your plan. In a course on Galois theory, you will want to show that every finite separable extension is contained in a finite Galois extension. Without this result, Galois theory is almost useless. And I don't see how you will prove this without doing something equivalent to constructing splitting fields.

Comment: @David: here is a way to express the same proof of Lemma 2 without the big matrix:  since $g$ is not a monomial (as $g(0) \ne 0$), $g(x)$ and $f(Tx)$ in $K[T,x]$ are relatively prime. Passing to $K(T)[x]$ allows us to write $h_1 g(x) + h_2 f(Tx) = 1$ in $K(T)[x]$ for some $h_1, h_2 \in K(T)[x]$. This all now makes sense in $K[T]_ h[x]$ for some nonzero $h \in K[T]$ (a "common denominator" of $h_1$ and $h_2$). Then we can specialize $T$ to any $t \in K$ that is not a zero of $h$, so $g(x)$ and $f(tx)$ are relatively prime in $K[x]$ away from that finite set of $t$. 

Comment: @David: I believe that the theorem that every finite separable extension is contained in a finite Galois extension is not going to hold constructively in general. It will hold for those fields where it is decidable whether not polynomials from F[X] are irreducible or not, and this is the case for most applications of Galois theory. I could restrict myself to fields of this type, but I don't like adding unnecessary hypothesis to my theorems.

If it makes you feel better, I'm not teaching a course, but making a proof in Coq (but your objection still applies, so I don't dismiss it out of hand).

Comment: @Boyarsky: thanks for your contribution.  I believe I can apply your argument (or at least something very close).

Comment: @Boyarsky: Why is it clear that $g(x)$ and $f(Tx)$ are relatively prime?

Comment: Any factor of g(x) would have to be a polynomial in $x$, any factor of $f(Tx)$ would have to be of the form (monomial in $T$ and $x$)*(polynomial in $Tx$). So any common factor would be a monomial in $x$.

Comment: @David: Why would any factor of f(Tx) factor into (monomial in T and x)*(polynomial in Tx)?  I mean, if f(x) factors into p(x)*q(x), then f(Tx) factors into p(Tx)*q(Tx), and this factorization isn't of that form.

Comment: Each factor of $f(Tx)$, namely $p(Tx)$ or $q(Tx)$ in your notation, is a polynomial in $Tx$.

Comment: @David: Okay, I now understand what you are saying about the shape of factors of f(Tx), but I still don't see why it is true.

Comment: @Russell: If $h(x)$ is a non-constant factor of $g(x)$ which divides $f(Tx)$ then consider the resulting identity $f(Tx) = h(x) H(x,T)$ for some $H$ in $K[x,T] = K[x][T]$. Comparing $T$-monomials separately, it follows that $h(x)$ divides every monomial which occurs in $f(x)$, so in particular $h$ is a monomial in $x$.  But $h$ is a non-constant factor of $g$, so then $g$ is divisible by $x$ and hence $g(0) = 0$, a contradiction. 

Comment: I have completed your proof (modulo a few typos) in Coq. I ended up using the big matrix, since currently the library for matrix algebra is currently more well developed than for GCD-domains. It is worth noting that you shouldn't factor &alpha; out of f.  If you do then you need to add the assumption that t &ne; 0.  Adding the assumption isn't bad, it's just that it comes for free if you don't factor out (X - &alpha;). A few other details become easier too with &alpha; left in.

Comment: @David Looking for a proof of the primitive element theorem lead me to your answer. You observe that the Bezout resultant is a non-zero polynomial in t, and conclude that it is not the zero polynomial function (of t), which is not always the case. Is it possible to clean the argument?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean that you want to avoid constructing splitting fields; you can't avoid talking about field extensions when proving a theorem about field extensions! Here's a sort of a proof, but I think it is probably cheating.

**Lemma:** Let $F$ be an infinite field. Let $V$ be a $K$ vector space, containing two linearly independent vectors $u$ and $v$. Let $W_1$, $W_2$, ..., $W_r$ be a finite list of subspaces of $V$, none of which contain the space spanned by $u$ and $v$. Then there are scalars $a$ and $b$ in $F$ such that $au+bv$ is not in any $W_i$.

**Proof:** Let $R$ be the plane spanned by $u$ and $v$. Since $W_i \not \supseteq R$, we know that $W_i \cap R$ has dimension at most $1$. So there is at most one ratio of $a/b$ for which $au+bv$ lies in $W_i$. Since $F$ is infinite, there are infinitely values of the ratio for which $au+bv$ is not in any $W_i$.

Now, take $V$ to be the field $F(\alpha, \beta)$, and take $W_i$ to be the list of proper subfields of $V$ containing $F$.

The problem is that this proof relies on the fact that *a finite seperable extension has finitely many sub-extensions.* I'm not sure it is possible to prove this without introducing splitting fields at some point.

Comment: Yes, I want to avoid constructing splitting field.  More generally I'm hoping to avoid the construction of adding arbitrary roots of polynomials to given fields.

Assume that $x$ and $y$ live in some given (finite) field extension $E/F$ that we know nothing about.  So we can talk about $K(z)$ and such for intermediate fields $K$ and elements $z \in E$, but not much else.

What you propose would work, but the theorem about finite separable extensions seems to require Galois theory, which is what I ultimately what I want to prove using the primitive element theorem.

Comment: Russell, two points.  (1) Having written the notes you linked to, I read them again and fixed a gap (concerning the distinction between uniquely extending derivations on a field step by step through a particular tower of fields and knowing there is only one extension to the top field). (2) If your goal is to develop Galois theory using the primitive element theorem, what is your reason for wanting to avoid splitting fields for the proof of the prim. elt. theorem? Presumably splitting fields will be in your proof of the Galois correspondence, as you indicate, so why not use them earlier too? 

Comment: And a third point:  that a finite separable extension has finitely many intermediate fields does *not* need Galois theory.  Sure, it is easy to understand why that theorem works from Galois theory, but a proof without Galois theory is definitely possible.  I think such an approach is in Artin's Notre Dame Galois theory notes (before he gets to Galois theory itself).  

Comment: @KConrad: are you sure Artin's proof of finiteness of the set of intermediate extensions doesn't use the primitive element theorem?  (Not that there's anything wrong with that; to be honest, I don't really understand the motivation behind the OP, since the usual arguments seem perfectly natural and elementary already.) 

Comment: @KConrad: re: (2).  Perhaps I haven't studied the proof of the fundamental theorem of Galois theory closely enough, but I don't see anywhere where objects outside the given Galois extensions are used.

Comment: Actually, we need a bit more since the OP is only assuming that one of the two elements is separable over F.

Comment: BC: Well, I don't have Artin's notes in front of me, but he was no fan of the primitive element theorem. You could do it this way: prove the primitive element theorem without Galois theory (see Lang's Algebra) and then prove one direction of Steinitz's theorem that a finite extension has a primitive element iff there are finitely many intermediate fields can be proved without Galois theory.  (Actually, Lang combines all of this into one theorem he calls the prim. elt. theorem.)  However, now I see Russell won't be happy because the argument in Lang uses embeddings into larger fields...

Comment: Kevin:  Although Russell states the primitive element theorem with the assumption that just one of the two elements is separable, that is excessive generality if the goal is Galois theory, where *everything* is separable.  For Russell's ultimate purpose I think his formulation of the primitive element theorem is too technical. Relax and assume both x and y are separable, which frankly is how that theorem is used most of the time anyway. 

Comment: Russell: Galois theory is all about (special kinds of) field extensions, so I don't see why you want to avoid using extensions going beyond your initial setting if it shortens proofs. How, then, can you accept the concept of a Galois extension in the first place, which is a particular extension of the original base field? Here's an example to think about. If A is a real symmetric matrix then its eigenvalues are all real, i.e., its char. poly. splits in R[x].  This has a *very short* proof using complex numbers. I don't a proof that avoids using C. Field extensions are your friend!

Comment: Russell:  I agree that one can ask for new proofs in a certain style, and this can lead to new insights even if the argument turns out to be longer. But in this particular case I think trying to avoid creating larger extensions which contain convenient objects is an  inconvenience. If the goal were to generalize Galois theory in some direction where "splitting fields" didn't occur, so the old proofs can't work, then that may be a compelling motivation.  For Galois theory itself, I think trying to avoid larger, but still just finite extensions, is not such a great idea. 

Comment: Russell:  As an example of something that I have tried to avoid when teaching Galois theory (say, to undergrads), I won't pull in algebraic closures since the existence of those for abstract fields is too much of a set-theoretic technicality.  So I can understand that you may want to see the subject unfold by avoiding a particular construction, but I don't see why the construction of field extensions should be the thing to avoid.  Artin, for instance, did not like the primitive elt. theorem because it made proofs depend on the choice of prim. element and thus seem less conceptual.

Comment: Russell: When I first taught Galois theory, I found that trying to avoid the prim. elt. thm. as a simplifying device in proofs made things more complicated. A prim. elt. explained many things very quickly. (In practice this did not seem to me to be like bases vs. coordinate-free methods in teaching linear algebra to math majors, while Artin may have thought the two were analogous.) So after that first experience I decided it's not so terrible to use the prim. elt. theorem in proofs. Maybe you'll come around in the same way on the prim. elt. thm. proof using new field extns. OK, that's all!

Comment: Russell: I think it would be a very bad idea not to teach your students that every finite separable extension is contained in a finite Galois extension. Without that, it is not clear that Galois theory is useful for anything. And I don't see how you are going to do that without adjoining roots of polynomials.